# scalafmt to check only modified files

Tags: scala, sbt, scalafmt

`sbt scalafmtCheckAll` checks the format of all files in the repo, how to check only the format of the modified files.

And whats the difference between `sbt scalafmtCheckAll` and `sbt scalafmtCheck`?

Comment: https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/installation.html#task-keys I don't think scalafmt alone can work on modified files only

Comment: How can I mix it with `git` to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you could use the `scalafmtFilter: diff-dirty` feature.

> [since v2.4.5] scalafmtFilter: String (default ""): optionally limits the set of files considered for formatting:
>
> - diff-dirty: only the files modified in the git working tree (git status)
> - diff-ref=: only the tracked files modified since  (git diff)
> - [since v2.4.6] none: no restrictions
> - otherwise if project.git = true (.scalafmt.conf): only files tracked by git (git ls-tree)
> - otherwise, no restrictions

See https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/installation.html#task-keys